# L2tp VPN connection plugin?

Tags: vpn

I have [L2tp VPN connection](http://www.ivpn.mobi) working on my Android device.

I wanted to add this to ubuntu through VPN connections, but I only found a PPTP plugin installed. I've searched a lot to find a way to add a lt2p plugin with no success.

I'm wondering is it that hard?

Answer (score 8):

Regarding Werner Jaeger's PPA: l2tp-ipsec-vpn seems to be in normal quantal/universe repository now, so you don't need adding any special PPA for it...

Comment: +1. It's also available directly in 13.10 (Saucy). So there's no need to add a special PPA any more.

Comment: this ugly client doen't work for me

Comment: Ugly yes but man it works! Make sure to reboot after installing!

Answer (score 3):

Open up a command prompt and type the following to install the client:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:werner-jaeger/ppa-werner-vpn
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install l2tp-ipsec-vpn
reboot
```

Check out [this guide](http://bailey.st/blog/2011/07/14/connecting-to-a-l2tpipsec-vpn-from-ubuntu-desktop/) for a full tutorial for configuring connection options after installation.  This is the easiest way that I have found for setting up an L2TP client on Ubuntu.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: `W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/werner-jaeger/ppa-werner-vpn/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.`

Answer (score 1):

Use https://launchpad.net/~seriy-pr/+archive/network-manager-l2tp

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:seriy-pr/network-manager-l2tp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp-gnome

sudo service xl2tpd stop
sudo update-rc.d xl2tpd disable
```

NEW for 16.04:

```
sudo apt install intltool libtool network-manager-dev libnm-util-dev libnm-glib-dev libnm-glib-vpn-dev libnm-gtk-dev libnm-dev libnma-dev ppp-dev strongswan libdbus-glib-1-dev libsecret-1-dev libgtk-3-dev libglib2.0-dev xl2tpd checkinstall

git clone https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp.git
cd network-manager-l2tp
autoreconf -fi
intltoolize

./configure --disable-static --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager --localstatedir=/var --with-pppd-plugin-dir=/usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7 
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: this PPA is out of date :(

Comment: add recipe for Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

VPN plugins are listed in Synaptic package manager as network-manager-[plugin] but there isn't one for L2TP at this time.

I managed to set up L2TP VPN manually (manually configuring the relevant conf files in the terminal) but this broke and I couldn't get it working again after upgrading to 11.10 (I haven't tried yet again in 12.04 but I think the things that "broke" in 11.10 are still broken).  Another option is to try using [Werner Jaeger's packages](https://launchpad.net/l2tp-ipsec-vpn).